# alternative to long list of nested ifelse statement with multiple conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

I have the following data frame

```
    structure(list(FY = c("2015-2016", "2015-2016", "2015-2016", 
"2015-2016"), YEARMN = structure(c(2015.25, 2015.25, 2015.25, 
2015.25), class = "yearmon"), BRAND = c("3M CAR CARE", "CAR CARE 3M", 
"CAR CARE 3M", "CAR CARE 3M"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("IstWEEKRent", "IIndWEEKRent", "IIIrdWEEKRent", 
"IVthWEEKRent", "mymonth"), class = "factor"), value = c("0", 
"17500", "85000", "212500"), mymonth = c("Apr", "Apr", "Apr", 
"Apr")), .Names = c("FY", "YEARMN", "BRAND", "variable", "value", 
"mymonth"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

The actual data frame looks like this:

```
         FY   YEARMN       BRAND      variable  value mymonth
1 2015-2016 Apr 2015 3M CAR CARE   IstWEEKRent      0     Apr
2 2015-2016 Apr 2015 CAR CARE 3M  IIndWEEKRent  17500     Apr
3 2015-2016 Apr 2015 CAR CARE 3M IIIrdWEEKRent  85000     Apr
4 2015-2016 Apr 2015 CAR CARE 3M  IVthWEEKRent 212500     Apr
```

The my month column has months from Apr to Mar...and every month has 4 weeks in my dataset which is given in column variable. I am trying to create a week number for the FY Apr - Mar, starting from 1 to 48.  I want to give week number 1 which matches the condition

```
variable == "IstWeekRent" & mymonth == "Apr"
```

I used ifelse function to get this done...which works fine...but when I include the same into my shiny application I am getting the following error:

```
Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
  contextstack overflow at line 2870
```

My current ifelse condition statement looks like this:

```
trndR$weeks <- ifelse(trndR$mymonth == "Apr" & trndR$variable == "IstWEEKRent", 1,
                ifelse(trndR$mymonth == "Apr" & trndR$variable == "IIndWEEKRent", 2,
                ifelse(trndR$mymonth == "Apr" & trndR$variable == "IIIrdWEEKRent", 3,
                ifelse(trndR$mymonth == "Apr" & trndR$variable == "IVthWEEKRent", 4,
                ifelse(trndR$mymonth == "May" & trndR$variable == "IstWEEKRent", 5,
                ifelse(trndR$mymonth == "May" & trndR$variable == "IIndWEEKRent", 6,
```

`trndR` is the name of my df and the condition extends upto 48.

I figured out that I can have only upto 50 nested ifelse condition...but not quite not sure how to rectify this.  I read about apply function but don't know how to use it in this case.

Comment: Is the data sorted? The data that you've shown looks like you've got a consistent 1 row per week, in which case the row number would probably suffice for your `weeks` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Try this:

```
mos <- month.abb[c(4:12, 1:3)] # Apr, May, ...., Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar
transform(trndR, weeks = 4 * (match(mymonth, mos)-1) + as.numeric(variable))
```

giving this using `trndR` posted in the question:

```
         FY  YEARMN       BRAND      variable  value mymonth weeks
1 2015-2016 2015.25 3M CAR CARE   IstWEEKRent      0     Apr     1
2 2015-2016 2015.25 CAR CARE 3M  IIndWEEKRent  17500     Apr     2
3 2015-2016 2015.25 CAR CARE 3M IIIrdWEEKRent  85000     Apr     3
4 2015-2016 2015.25 CAR CARE 3M  IVthWEEKRent 212500     Apr     4
```

This should work even if the rows are not sorted and even if there are missing weeks.

**1a)** This alternative is shorter (only one line) but perhaps not as clear:

```
transform(trndR, weeks = 4*((match(mymonth, month.abb)-4) %% 12) + as.numeric(variable))
```

**2)** If the rows are sorted and there are no missing weeks then this would work as well

```
transform(trndR, weeks = 1:nrow(trndR))
```

Comment: How does `as.numeric` convert the character strings to numeric? I can see it might be possible, but I can't get it (just that conversion) working for me.

Comment: They are not character -- they are factor.  Try `str(trndR)`

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that! Makes the problem a whole lot easier! Thanks.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Many thanks for a very elegant answer.  Truly appreciate. This works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your data, you should be able to just make sure everything is in the correct order, then call each row a particular week. For example (edited slightly after G.Grothendieck pointed out to me that the `variable` column is factor, their answer seems more tidy than mine, but I'll leave this here anyway in case it is of any interest):

```
# get a value from 1 to 4, representing the `variable` column numerically
trndR$weeks <- as.numeric( trndR$variable )

# now sort the dataframe by `YEARMN` and `weeks` respectively to make sure everything is in order
trndR <- trndR[ with( trndR, order( YEARMN, weeks ) ), ]

# and replace that new `weeks` column with a sequence
trndR$weeks <- seq_along( trndR$weeks )
```

It looks like your data contains one financial year, but if not, you could rewrite the last line of the above to apply it per financial year (assuming each FY is fully represented in your dataset):

```
library( data.table )
setDT( trndR )[ , weeks := seq_len( 48 ), by = FY ]
```

Comment: Many thanks....I tried your solution...however, the seq_along filled the column weeks with sequential numbers starting from 1 to 1256...whereas I was looking for a week number that will range from 1 to 48   (considering 4 weeks a months).  Many thanks again...your solution certainly helped me to know a different solution.....I was struggling with this since last morning.  And I was subsetting by FY before applying the ifelse.

Comment: Did you use the last section (with `data.table`)? That should avoid the long sequence you're talking about. Anyway, I'm glad you found a solution.